# Wireless router restarts frequently

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-router

I have a ZTE zxv10 w300 4port wireless router at my home. When I connected to the router through wire I can connect to the internet without any problem. But, when I connect through the wireless connection after few minutes router restart several times and wireless connection turn off automatically. I can connect to the internet only a few minutes using the wireless connection, is this could be a defect of the router? or if not what could be the reason for this, please assist me.

Comment: How old is the router? Maybe the hardware itself is going bad.

Answer (score 1):

this can be a firmware bug, try to update the routers firmware, ZTE website to know how-to. also this could happen when your having small buffer ( which is used with most low quality routers) and you are making huge traffic(gaming, downloading, video streaming..etc) that is all what i can think of at the moment :)